# Specifying a dependency of a version greater than N and less than M

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, packaging

Is it possible to specify the dependency of another library that is within a specific range of versions?

Like:

```
Depends: Lib (<= 4) -- dependency of a library that has version less or equal to 4      
Depends: Lib (>= 2) -- dependency of a library that has version more or equal to 2
```

But could we combine them? So that the overall constraint expressed `the version is more or equal to 2 and less or equal to 4`?

PS: this is just an academic question, out of curiosity (since I couldn't find it in debian http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't test it but as comma is equal to an `and` this could work:

```
Depends: Lib (<= 4), Lib (>= 2)
```

Comment: I was thinking of `Lib (<= 4, >= 2)` but still would be nice to see the complete guide on that :-)

Comment: @zerkms if you look at the policy it states that only a relationship + version number is allowed: `This is done in parentheses after each individual package name; the parentheses should contain a relation from the list below followed by a version number`, i.e. your suggested version isn't covered.

Comment: +1 There are real-world examples of this; just grep a recent Packages file.

Comment: Try the Debian documentation: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

Comment: FYI the url to that debian policy has changed - try https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#document-ch-relationships

Answer (score 1):

I found an more complete answer to this question on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/918432/366935) (which also includes specifying dependencies conditionally):

```
Lib (>= 2), Lib (<< 4)
```